# Finding the wavelength of acoustic source underwater

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics

I am currently working on a data fit assignment for my class and ran into some confusion. I will post the entire question here so you can get some background but the only question I have is with what's given. As you can see we are given a frequency (120kHz) and the diamter of the source (6cm). What I need to continue with my project is a(Radius of the source) and lambda(wavelength of the acoustic field. For a I am assuming its 3cm from what is given and for lambda I used lambda = v/f where v is 1600m/s underwater and f is 120 which resulted in lambda = 0.0133. Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Water), the speed of sound in fresh water is about $1500\text{ m}/\text{s}$, meaning that at 120 KHz, 
$$\lambda=f/v=0.0125\text{m}.$$

As is readily verified, with $a=0.03\text{m}$, there are two nodes present:

```
Plot[Abs[Sin[a/\[Lambda] \[Pi] r (Sqrt[1 + 1/r^2] - 1)]] /. {a -> 
0.03, \[Lambda] -> 0.0125}, {r, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image]

There is an intuitive explanation for why nodes appear or not: when the ratio $a/\lambda$ is small, the disk basically looks like a point source, which obviously has no nodes. But when $a/\lambda$ is large, it's no longer like a point source, and the contribution from the various parts of the disk surface can interfere and cancel to form regions where there is no sound pressure.

Comment: I believe a is 3cm but this helps thanks

Comment: Also, do you get the graph they give as an example of a and lambda are 1??

Comment: Yes, it reproduces the picture. Also, in the future, please try to do more work on the problem before posting and specifically highlight which conceptual issues you are having difficulty with; the homework guideline is at http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/. Otherwise the question is liable to be closed as being off-topic, since it doesn't contribute to the library of broad conceptual knowledge which the site is supposed to represent.

Comment: OK thank you that makes sense. I guess I am having trouble with my matlab code but at least I understand the concept.

Comment: Actually I posted below what I got. Let me know what you think. I believe you made a mistake in that you used 120Hz instead of 120kHz. You also used 3m instead of 3 cm. Am i heading down the right track?

Comment: I cant post answers yet but basically I got wavelength of 1482/120000 which is .01235. I believe 1482 is a more accurate number than 1500. And a is .03. And when plotting I got 2 nodes. Please let me know if you get the same. Thank You!

Comment: @user126582: Yeah, you're right, I wasn't paying attention to units, I edited the answer to fix it.